# size of textarea in chrome and firefox is different

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am facing an issues regarding the size of textarea tag in html. when i open the page in chrome it opens with different height and when i open that page in firefox then the size of that textarea is different.
Kindly tell me the solution of this problem.
Thanks
Kind Regards

Comment: please show us doctype, markup and css you're using

Comment: Add css `textarea { width: 50px; height: 50px; }`

Comment: i have done it with textarea css.. THanks alone evenings :)

Answer (score -1):

you have to write conditional css in your css file so check out this